# Correctly configuring TexWorks to work with TexLive (TUGs version)

Tags: installing, texlive, texworks, linux

I just downloaded TL 2010 but the packages don't seem available to TexWorks.  Before I was using the version of TL supplied via Synaptic.  But that was not being kept up to date so I had to download TUGs version into what will be a separately maintained directory.

But I don't know how to configure my editors (TexWorks is the primary editor I use, TexMaker is my secondary editor) to be able to tap into the new package repository I've created.  I'm working within Debian Squeeze.

I used default paths in my installation.

It was suggested I edit the .profile file - this is where I'm at at the moment:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/i386-linux:$PATH 

MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH 

INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH
```

Comment: TL 2011? not 2010 (the current version)?

Comment: Did you add the necessary TeX Live paths (in the .profile directory)?

Comment: @Caramdir Thanks, I meant 2010.  OP edited with that correction now.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina ".profile directory", where do I find that?

Comment: It's usually in `/home/your_user_name/`; you need to edit this file and add something like `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` 
`MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH`
`INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH` the last part of the first line can be different in a 32bit installation.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: see OP.  I've done as you said and I still get "! LaTeX Error: File `chemmacros.sty' not found."  If TexWork were looking in the correct version of TL, it would've found chemmacros.sty.  Suggestions?

Comment: Try compiling a simple, basic  (without any special packages) test document first. My TeX Live installation (full TeX Live2010) doesn't come with `chemmacros.sty`.

Comment: After adding the `PATH` lines to your `.profile`, don't forget to logout and login again.

Comment: `chemmacros.sty` was released on May 15. It is already in TeX Live, but it usually takes some time until the changes propagate to the mirrors. For example, on my system TL defaults to the mirror provided by the [University of Idaho](http://mirror.its.uidaho.edu/pub/tex-archive/systems/texlive/), which was last updated on May 11. Thus it can't possibly have `chemmacros.sty`. Try using a different [mirror](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/CTAN.sites) or wait a few days to get the package.

Comment: Ok, one way to settle this - although I think I'm sure I saw chemmacros.sty being installed while I watched the installation, is there a command that will allow me to check?  Where is the packages directory?  The general TL directory I installed to was usr/local/texlive/2010

Comment: Run `kpsewhich chemmacros.sty` in a terminal. If the package is installed, the you'll get its path; if it's not installed, then the command will return nothing. But, did you test your installation with a simple document?

Comment: Yes: peter@debian-peter:~$ kpsewhich chemmacros.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemmacros/chemmacros.sty.


And yes, it can compile a document fine with the text "hello world".

Comment: So, is your problem solved? If not, build a minimal document illustrating your problem(s) and report any error messages obtained during compilation.

Comment: Sadly, no, my problem persists.  TexWorks cannot find packages that should be there.  It may still be looking in my previous texlive directories which came with the linux distribution, instead of the newly installed TUGs directories...

Comment: I've experienced the same thing. Packages are definately installed, but they're not found when compiling in TeXworks, and IIRC, not when running `pdflatex` in a terminal either. What's weird though, is that it works just fine in Emacs and Kile ...

Comment: Open TeXworks and go to `Edit`->`Preferences`. Select the `Typesetting` tab and check the section `Paths for TeX and related programs` to verify that they are set properly to the TeXLive2010 installation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working with Debian Squeeze, TL2010 and TeXworks, too.

This is how I did it:

1. Use synaptic to uninstall all packages starting with "texlive-"
2. Download and unpack TL2010 installer
3. Open "Root Terminal, start installer with "./install-tl"
4. Select option "Create symlinks to standard directories" (by using this there is no need to edit any files like .profile)
5. Start installation of TeXlive
6. Test TeXlive with "pdflatex sample2e"
7. "apt-get update" and "apt-get install perl-tk perl-doc equivs"
8. Create and install texlive-local_2009-1_all.deb (see http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html)
9. "apt-get install texworks" (this should NOT install any TeX related packages except texworks itself!)
10. Test TeXworks
11. "tlmgr update --all" (to test if the update mechanism of TeXlive works fine)

Comment: I used the GUI wizard install; I don't remember getting a create symlinks option.  Can you clarify the situation with GUI wizard install?

Comment: I don't know where to find this option in the GUI installation wizard, but you can create the symlinks after installation, too. Just start "tlmgr gui" as root and go to the menu "Actions" => "Handle symlinks in system dirs..."

Comment: Slight problem you might be able to help with.  It's a silly catch 22 situation actually.  I need to launch tlmgr as root to have access to config options but tlmgr isn't recognised when I try to launch it as root:-  sudo: tlmgr: command not found

Comment: Also I get this:

peter@debian-peter:~$ tlmgr gui
No protocol specified
perl/Tk unusable, cannot create main windows.
That could be a consequence of not having X Windows installed or started!
Error message from creating MainWindow:
  couldn't connect to display ":0" at /usr/lib/perl5/Tk/MainWindow.pm line 55.
Tk::MainWindow->new() at /usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/i386-linux/tlmgr line 3590

Comment: Haven't I already added the path to .profile (see OP)?

Comment: @Jasper Joy In any case, I've done as you've suggested, updated the symbolic links using tlmgr gui.  TexWorks is still not able to fined chemmacros.sty, which is definitely installed.  It is either looking for it in the wrong place still after all that, or I don't know...

Comment: @Jasper Joy There maybe several factors thwarting my efforts here: first, the path /usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/i386-linux wasn't there in the "Paths for Tex and related programs" menu.  So I added it.  Second, the package chemmacros was stipulating other packages and the use of something called "\usetikzlibrary{calc}" which I don't understand.  Bottom line it finally seemed to work, but because I'd tried so many things at once I'm still unsure what finally did it.  Some or all of the above.  Thanks everyone for your help.  Good grief, now I have to go troubleshoot similar issues on Windows. :|

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing a different configuration. 2 Possible ways to do that:

1. In the GUI of TeXworks, you can choose
   Edit -> Preferences -> Typesetting
   and add to "Paths for Tex and related programs" the path

   /usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/i386-linux

or

```
/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-linux
```

resp.
2. With the same effect, you can add this path in the file

```
~/.config/TUG/TeXworks.conf
```

in the line starting with

```
binaryPaths=
```